# Cannot deploy stream through spring-cloud-dataflow-server in sap-cloud-foundry

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I deployed spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry to SAP Cloud Fondry with environments below:

```
SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_URL:https://api.cf.sap.hana.ondemand.com
SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ORG:{org}
SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_SPACE:{space}
SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_DOMAIN:{doamin}
SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_USERNAME:username
SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_PASSWORD:password
SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_SKIP_SSL_VALIDATION:false
SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_STREAM_SERVICES: mq
```

And import stream starter apps using bulk import applications.
And I create stream using "time-source-rabbit-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar" and "log-sink-rabbit-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar".

But I cannot deploy stream. 
The status is "partial" fianlly, and apps' runtime are failed.

My question is:
1. Whether spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry can be used in SAP cloud foundry like I used?
2. When deploy stream in cloudfoundry using spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry dashboard, should I set any other necessary properties?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the `manifest.yml`, it appears that `org`, `space`, and `domain` weren't replaced with SAP-CF specific values. Pay attention to the following note in the [ref. guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/docs/1.2.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#running-on-cloudfoundry).

> Now we can configure the app. The following configuration is for Pivotal Web Services. You need to fill in {org}, {space}, {email} and {password} before running these commands.

If you have them replaced with your environment specific properties, the next step is to check the SCDF-server's logs. There will be particular details as to why the deployment failed if it did.

Now to answer your questions.

For #1, it is hard to say without logs or environment details. We don't actively test against SAP distribution of Cloud Foundry. As far as the distribution is compatible with Diego 1.7.1 and over, it should work. We also publish the CF compatible versions in [project site](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/#pcf-vs-oss-cf-compatibility). Perhaps this could be useful to compare the SAP CF environment and its foundation versions.

For #2, no, you don't need any other properties.